# How can I create a sub-list from a list in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class:

```
class person{
             string first_name;
             string middle_name;
             string last_name;
             string adress;
             string phone;
           }
```

and I have a list of class person:

```
List<person> person_list= new List<person>();
```

I like to create a sub list of person contains only first, middle and last name.

I tried:

```
var sub_list = (from item in person_list 
                select new {item.first_name , 
                            item.middle_name , 
                            item.last_name});
```

and it's work.
But I don't want "var" type because I can't pass the sub_list to another function. how can I put a type instead of var?

Comment: Well you can write your own class that contains only those properties... (As an aside, now would be a good time to look at and start following the .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: create a new class with those properties

Comment: I think this question shows a lock of understanding of `var`. `var` is not a type. A variable initialized with `var` still gets a definite type, and can still be passed from one function to another, whereas you said you don't want `var` because then you can't pass it to another function.

Comment: Aye its not var that is the problem it is the anonymous type.

Comment: You can find those naming conventions Job mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx). `person` would become `Person`, `first_name` would become `FirstName`, `person_list` would become `personList` etc.

Comment: – Kevin Wells , is it possible to pass var object? or I have to convert it to a type at first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view model for your person:

```
class PersonVM 
{
    string first_name;
    string middle_name;
    string last_name;
}

IEnumerable<PersonVM> sub_list = from item in person_list 
                    select new PersonVM {
                         first_name = item.first_name , 
                         middle_name = item.middle_name, 
                         last_name = item.last_name
                    };
```

Comment: Exactly!! Thanks very much.